# Clarification of UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 encoding when used with JSP pages, and Tomcat

Tags: jsp, tomcat, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I must be having issues putting two and two together when it comes to encoding but there are quite a few stackoverflow questions regarding encoding so I must not be the only one!  Currently, I have a simple JSP page that has a struts action form containing a single user text input with a default value of PÃ mies OlivÃ©s.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>

<form method="get" action="login.jsp">
```

```
<tr><td>Full Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="fullName" value="PÃ mies OlivÃ©s" size="35"></td></tr>


<tr><td colspan="2"><br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td></tr>
```

If a user hits submit with that default value I have a scriptlet output the user's inputted value to the page so I can see it.  I get the expected PÃ mies OlivÃ©s when having Tomcat and the page's charset set to UTF-8.  However, if I try to use ISO-8859-1 encoding in Tomcat I get an output of PÃÂ mies OlivÃÂ©s or if I set both Tomcat and the charset of the page to ISO-8859-1 the value becomes PÃƒÂ mies OlivÃƒÂ©s.  What would be causing this discrepancy with the ISO-8859-1 encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoding of POST form data is usually controlled by the `accept-charset` attribute on the `form` element.

A POST form definition should look like:

```
<form method="get" action="login.jsp" accept-charset="iso-8859-1" >
```

For GET requests, HTML 4 recommends UTF-8 encoding for the query string, which what you'll be using as the method is "GET".

`accept-charset="iso-8859-1"` may force the browser to encode the query string to iso-8859-1 but I don't think it'll be very reliable.

Instead, try to use POST if possible.

I appreciate that your question may be academic, but I would recommend that you use UTF-8 for forms so that you're not limiting them to a <255 unique characters.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Adding the accept-charset attribute cleared up the encoding issues I was having.  I'd up the answer but I don't have 15 rep...